# Different class component and func component in handle event react

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me explain it, because when use functional it work, but not when use class component
Different class component and func component in handle event react.

fyi it take input text search on child and at parent doing handle event and other

child use functional

```
import React from "react";

const Header = ({searchTitle,onSearch}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>Notes</h1>
        <div className="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={searchTitle}
            onChange={onSearch}
          ></input>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

child use class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class HeaderPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const searchTitle = this.props.searchTitle;
    const onSearch = this.props.onSearchHandler;

    return (
      <header>
        <h1>Notes</h1>
        <div className="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={searchTitle}
            onChange={onSearch}
          ></input>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderPage;
```

parent class componet

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import HeaderPage from "../organisms/HeaderPage";
import MainPage from "../organisms/MainPage";
import FooterPage from "../organisms/FooterPage";

import { getInitialData } from "../../utils/data";
import Header from "../organisms/Header";

export class PageNote extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataNotes: getInitialData(),
      dataNotesFiltered: [],
      searchTitle: "",
    };

    //binding
    this.onAddNoteHandler = this.onAddNoteHandler.bind(this);
    this.onDeleteHandler = this.onDeleteHandler.bind(this);
    this.onArchivedHandler = this.onArchivedHandler.bind(this);
    this.onSearchHandler = this.onSearchHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onAddNoteHandler({ title, body }) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        dataNotes: [
          ...prevState.dataNotes,
          {
            id: +new Date(),
            title,
            body,
            archived: false,
            createdAt: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  }

  onDeleteHandler(id) {
    const dataNotes = this.state.dataNotes.filter(
      (dataNote) => dataNote.id !== id
    );
    this.setState({ dataNotes });
  }

  onArchivedHandler(id) {
    const dataNotes = this.state.dataNotes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === id) {
        return { ...note, archived: !note.archived };
      } else {
        return note;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ dataNotes });
  }

  onSearchHandler(event) {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        searchTitle: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.dataNotes);
    console.log(`search ${this.state.searchTitle}`);
    const dataNotes = this.state.dataNotes.filter((note) =>
      note.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTitle.toLowerCase())
    );
    return (
      <>
        <HeaderPage
          searchTitle={this.state.searchTitle}
          onSearch={this.onSearchHandler}
        ></HeaderPage>
        <Header
          searchTitle={this.state.searchTitle}
          onSearch={this.onSearchHandler}
        ></Header>
        <MainPage
          dataNotes={dataNotes}
          addNote={this.onAddNoteHandler}
          onDelete={this.onDeleteHandler}
          onArchive={this.onArchivedHandler}
        ></MainPage>
        <FooterPage></FooterPage>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PageNote;
```

Comment: The class component expects an `onSearchHandler` prop; none is provided.

Comment: i put onSearchHandler on parent component, it work for funct but not work on class component

Comment: That's not what your code shows. Your `<HeaderPage>` usage passes `onSearch`, the component accesses `this.props.onSearchHandler`.